# TabHost NullPointerException using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I’m using Sherlock library and I want to create a tab in my app but I’m getting a `NullPointerException`; what am I doing wrong?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitesherlock/com.example.bonsitesherlock.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:229)
    at com.example.bonsitesherlock.MainActivity.addTab(MainActivity.java:49)
    at com.example.bonsitesherlock.MainActivity.setTabs(MainActivity.java:32)
    at com.example.bonsitesherlock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
    ... 11 more
```

This is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  
        setTabs();
    } 

    private void setTabs()
    { 
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_news, News.class);
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_servises, News.class);
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_profile, News.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);    

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon); 
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);      
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Comment: What tabs do you have? Are they fragments or activities? Are they in the manifest? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396037/tabhost-null-pointer-exception

Comment: Edited to be more succinct.

Comment: Just a guess. Have you tried setting the TabHost in onCreateView? It's possible that it's null because the content view has not yet been initialised during onCreate.